# Can't find error!! Trying to loop throught a string and change lowercase to uppercase letter in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data   
  msg db  "sum of x and y is " ;String
section .text
global _start
_start:
Change_letter:
  mov ECX, -1 ;set counter 
  mov ESI, [msg] ; move string address to ESI
  mov Eax , 32 ; mov 32 to eax for change lowercase to uppercase
startloop:
  inc ecx  ; 
  cmp byte [ESI+ecx], 0x00 ;compare with null 
  jne end
  cmp byte [ESI+ECX], 0x61 ; compare with lower bound of lowercase 
  jl startloop
  cmp byte [ESI+ECX], 0x7A
  jg startloop
  add byte [ESI+ECX], eax
end:
  ret
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. Hint: what do you think `jne end` will do?

Comment: You guys must admit that this program runs very fast. <g>

Answer (score 6):

How many errors do you want?

```
section .data   
  msg db  "sum of x and y is " ;String
section .text
global _start
_start:
Change_letter:
  mov ECX, -1 ;set counter 
  mov ESI, [msg] ; move string address to ESI
```

This loads `esi` with first 4 characters of the string, not address.

```
  mov Eax , 32 ; mov 32 to eax for change lowercase to uppercase
startloop:
  inc ecx  ; 
  cmp byte [ESI+ecx], 0x00 ;compare with null 
  jne end
```

First letter is different than zero value, so the `jne` will jump to `end:`. Also you didn't define zero byte in the `msg`, so once you will flip the condition to `je`, you are in risk of processing many more bytes after the defined `msg`, up till some random zero is accidentally found in memory (practically there will be one right after `msg` as padding, so you would not notice this error unless you reason about your code properly).

```
  cmp byte [ESI+ECX], 0x61 ; compare with lower bound of lowercase 
  jl startloop
```

When dealing with ASCII values, I rather tend to think about them in unsigned way, i.e. `jb`, not `jl`. Also instead of `0x61` you can use with NASM `'a'`, it's IMO more readable.

```
  cmp byte [ESI+ECX], 0x7A
  jg startloop
```

Again I would rather use unsigned jump `ja`, and `'z'` constant.

```
  add byte [ESI+ECX], eax
```

How does this even compile... `eax` is 32 bits, not 8 bits, so the `byte` keyword is probably ignored. If you would switch all warnings ON, the NASM would probably emit some (too lazy to try myself). Also you are adding `32` to the lowercase letters, so from `0x61` for `'a'` you will go to value `0x81`, which in linux is unprintable character when interpreted as 7b ASCII (although with UTF-8 encoding or some other you may get some output).

```
end:
  ret
```

And after damaging single lowercase letter, you fall-through to the `end:`.

Enough? And use debugger, it takes years of experience to spot assembly bugs by reading the source, even just reading the debugger screen often takes high level of focus, to actually notice the subtle discrepancy against your original expectation, like 0x91 instead of 0x61 will almost certainly look good at first sight, etc... Don't let your brain deceive you, it takes practice and skill to overcome these.

Comment: `add byte [ESI+ECX], eax` doesn't assemble with NASM 2.13.02.    `error: mismatch in operand sizes`.